# I'm unsure what the problem with my assembly code it works until eax is popped and replaced by a register

Tags: debugging, x86

```
; Input x and y, output min of the two numbers
.586
.MODEL FLAT
INCLUDE io.h
.STACK 4096

.DATA
number  DWORD   ?
array   DWORD   20, 15, 62, 40, 18
nbrElts DWORD   5
prompt  BYTE    "Enter value:", 0
string  BYTE   80 DUP (?)
resultLbl BYTE  "Position", 0
result  BYTE    11 DUP (?), 0

.CODE
_MainProc PROC
        input   prompt, string, 20      ; read ASCII characters
        atod    string                  ; convert to integer
        mov     number, eax             ; store in memory
        
        push    nbrElts         ; 3rd parameter (# of elements in array)
        lea     eax, array      ; 2nd parameter (address of array)
        push    eax
        push    number          ; 1st parameter (value from user)
        call    searchArray     ; searchArray(number, array, 5)
        add     esp, 12     
        
        dtoa    result, eax     ; convert to ASCII characters
        output  resultLbl, result  ; output label and result

        mov     eax, 0  ; exit with return code 0
        ret
_MainProc ENDP

; searchArray(int x, array, int y)
; 
searchArray   PROC
        push    ebp             ; save base pointer
        mov     ebp, esp        ; establish stack frame
        push    eax             ; save registers
        push    ebx
        push    esi
        push    ecx
        push    edx
        
        mov     ebx, [ebp+8]    ; x, value from user
        mov     esi, [ebp+12]   ; address of array
        mov     ecx, [ebp+16]   ; y, number of elements
        mov     edx, 1
        
        mov     ecx, 5

        forLoop:
        mov     eax, [esi]      ; a[i]
        cmp     eax, ebx        ; eax = ebx ?
        je      isEqual
        ;cmp     eax, ebx
        add     esi, 4
        inc     edx
        loop    forLoop
        ;mov     eax, 0

        cmp     edx, 6
        je      notEqual

        isEqual:
        mov     eax, edx
        jmp     exitCode
        
        notEqual:
        mov     eax, 0
        jmp     exitCode

        exitCode:
        mov     eax, edx
        pop     edx             ; restore EBP
        pop     ecx             ; restore EAX
        pop     esi
        pop     ebx
        pop     ebp
        ret                     ; return      
searchArray   ENDP

END                           ; end of source code
```

Answer (score 2):

The pops at the end of the function need to match the pushes at the beginning of the function. If they don't match, the stack pointer ends up in the wrong place and the ret returns to the wrong place.

In your case, you have an extra  push without a corresponding pop.

The reason to push registers at the beginning and pop them at the end is to preserve their values. But you don't want to preserve the value of eax. You want to return a different value, the result of the function. So there is absolutely no reason to push eax.